# What makes WP so SEO friendly?

Tags: seo, google-search, search-engines

I keep hearing that Wordpress is the best SEO solution, better than most static websites because of multiple reasons. I then go on to hear contradicting information elsewhere. So: Is Wordpress generally more SEO friendly/ready then most static html websites? What makes it more SEO friendly? Can I take any SEO tips from a Wordpress installation to improve a static HTML page SEO?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you hear about SEO-friendliness of CMS it is essentially same as for static page - how URL looks and what gets into source of page.

Essentially WP is considered SEO-friendly because:

1. It is easy to get [pretty permalinks](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks) enabled and working
2. There is large choice of themes and plugins, aimed at following recommended SEO guidelines (titles, meta tags, structure of headings, etc).

So this is not about WP being somehow unique. It is about it having tools (both native and extensions) to follow good practices for on-page SEO.

Comment: so I would have to end up looking into the good SEO package extensions that wordpress to figure out how to better my seo skills?

Comment: You'd just have to better your SEO skills in general. The SEO plugins out there are tools that make it easier to deal with the fundamentals of site optimization.  They're not going to teach you about keyword target or research or reporting or anything like that.

Answer (score 1):

WordPress doesn't give you tips for SEO, it just makes it easier to deal with SEO settings. You don't need to code every meta fiels, because you have it provided. Similarly, you get permalinks option and can choose the looks and structure of your URLs.

But if you know nothing about SEO rules and techniques, this won;t help you. With SEO, it is you who's the master and WordPress is a great tool that makes your job easier.

Answer (score 1):

WordPress is SEO friendly as anyone can implement things that are important for SEO. For this you need to first understand SEO rules and its technique that is how you would be able to make use of WordPress in better way. It is simple, easy and quick to use

Answer (score 1):

Basically permalinks is easy to setup then there are seo optimization tools are paid and non paid available. Some of common use plugin are

- All in one SEO
- yoast seo
- XML Sitemap Generator for WordPress
- W3catch or Wp rocket
- Meta slider (for SEO optimize image slider)

And finally , its relatively easy to find more plugin and themes as needed.